# Inferring parameter of method of generic class from union type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have this use case, where I have a generic class, and a container class that contains multiple members of the generic class. I would like to use `setViaFunction` to set members of the container class not depending on their type. However I get the following error: `Argument of type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2345)` [typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDiCmA7eAnAlsAwuKAeAKgHzQDeAUNJdAA4CuARiBtAG5gi3wBc0+FVwAPaIIAFxS1gowSgAUAfTYduvAJTkqm6KIAWaCADolnaAF5oi9p36UAvjegR4ogGpX4C493zqHm3fpG7mYWXg729mSgkDCYwqJgaMgo2DGkDmI6AMriSQDmIcgA7nBIqBipULIA5BAAJmB11apkGboAQoKCIPBgiIXwJQjJFTgQsuKcLRnOAIKIAJ4AsvAAtvSoIbIAZmjwIHU8tbo56Ih51dAAPtDHOp3dvYjVADSs7DxiZwU39F09fVUZmIGioAQgAG1dvs6gBdILKEJKcIzVxoMAAMVoiCkaGEW2hByOmVO+UuNzuDwBzzeSk+uXO12gf0egOB6X8ekhhLhBicrncsiULU0ESAA)

Also note that `setAnyMember` which manually does the same thing, but is not always possible to do doesn't produce that error.

Is there another way to achieve this functionality in typescript?

```
class GenericClass<T> {
    public value: T
    constructor(_value: T){
        this.value = _value
    }
    setValue(_value:T){
        this.value = _value
    }
}

class ContainerClass {
    sthString = new GenericClass('sdad')

    sthBoolean = new GenericClass(true)

    setAnyMember = (field: 'sthString' | 'sthBoolean', val: string | boolean) => {
    this[field].value = val
    }
    setViaFunction = (field: 'sthString' | 'sthBoolean', val: string | boolean) => {
    this[field].setValue(val)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the assignment is not failing cause the types match

`this[field].value` is of type `string | boolean`
and val is too.

If you try to call `this[field].setValue(val)` typescript is not smart enough to figure out the types by itself :/.

I can't think of a smart way to help typescript to pick the right type automatically.

I would try to solve this by not passing field and calling the right method by the type of val

```
class ContainerClass {
    sthString = new GenericClass('sdad')

    sthBoolean = new GenericClass(true)

    setAnyMember = (field: 'sthString' | 'sthBoolean', val: string | boolean) => {
    this[field].value = val
    }
    setViaFunction = (val: string | boolean) => {
        if (typeof val === "string"){
            this.sthString.setValue(val)
        } else {
            this.sthBoolean.setValue(val)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's define our util types:

```js
class GenericClass<T> {
    public value: T
    constructor(_value: T) {
        this.value = _value
    }

    setValue(_value: T) {
        this.value = _value
    }
}

// infer generic parameter from GenericClass
type GetGeneric<T> = T extends GenericClass<infer G> ? G : never
{
    type Test = GetGeneric<GenericClass<boolean>> // boolean
}

// infer all props which are instances of GenericClass
type GetProps<T> = {
    [Prop in keyof T]: T[Prop] extends GenericClass<any> ? Prop : never
}[keyof T]
{
    type Test = GetProps<ContainerClass> // "sthString" | "sthBoolean"
}

// infer correct type of GenericClass constructor argument
type GetValues<Obj, Prop> = Prop extends GetProps<Obj> ? GetGeneric<Obj[Prop]> : never
{
    type Test = GetValues<ContainerClass, 'sthString'> // string
}

class ContainerClass {
    sthString = new GenericClass('sdad')

    sthBoolean = new GenericClass(true)
    /**
     * Field is one of "sthString" | "sthBoolean"
     */
    setAnyMember<Field extends GetProps<this>>(
        /**
         * this is a Record with Field keys and appropriate GenericClass instances
         */
        this: Record<Field, GenericClass<GetValues<this, Field>>>,
        field: Field, // "sthString" | "sthBoolean"
        val: GetValues<this, Field> // get value by Field key
    ) {
        this[field].setValue(val) // ok

    }
}
const x = new ContainerClass();
x.setAnyMember('sthBoolean', true) // ok
x.setAnyMember('sthString', 'str') // ok

x.setAnyMember('sthBoolean', 32) // expected error
x.setAnyMember('sthString', false) // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDiCmA7eAnAlsAwuKAeAKgHzQDeAUNJdAA4CuARiBtAG5gi3wBc0%20FVwAPaIIAFxS1gowSgAUAfTYduvAJSl%20VKqIAWaCADolnaAF5oi9p03QAvmRsR4ogGpX4C4yvzryWrbr6Ru5mFl429vZkAPTR0GiIAGao0ADmSKjM1GAoYAC2zimJKIJ5cBnoWDgQZKIAntTw5aIIyJUExOb40PAAHqJIACYwrZlVkBC4CckocMQA-HDQPMgsqGR%202g1N%20PBioQgtFRi4o5XYE7j0goIg8GCIhMSx0Ne394hkUS-TKewgNBK1BgAHc9MAdNAck0EmIHsA9tBBIlym0MBcoLVts0AApAyZEUKbSgAbTxgmo8UQ0AA1vA6sjeABdHj4MlApk9fpDEbHcZ4B51BbQcmUlbwNYoL4kukMlH4JkbGz1Rq8PaiA7OUWTTDCURgBKoDEQZ5xABEYh0AGVxAlUmboAAfaAW3QAIRudweZq%20Dh%20SRSQhQKHgUmgKqajLO6Oq0CEInEkmksxyqVoBUQoixqsObmUkwA8vQAFYAGhFQM6FYpXIGiGGuPxuCLxeFh2jwGbJfZFKZxHFkqVAWxu325lz7h1eoNbWN5YA5JabehEKl56boGIV6lfWRQBNoLrMzOjbHiZvdMu7aFkCDUWNjbJF4MwIN56oHFpLR73g8b-A7w7R9E3gD9HGcABBRA6gAWXgPJ6FQXAADE0HgEBBlrHlGwpSZAhNQhZBsAI9AgHgACVQxkQYULQjDyyA6pTmcPNODw0jy1Q9DBieQhS2IqhEjowYeC4%20iBMoJQeAnfNcHwzjhMIGxfAk8NSJJITuKZAwnFcdxZCUdQXkEGlPyoSI92EfZen-O8j31Q0UEfVQAG4yF6HTIOguCENQJ9v09D553LECjLiEz3M80QoNg%20DELkRdL1tVdgugRKUHfaBjNMyLdJinz4v891AoeVKAGYACYwq5RopHgTDUBKKUPLy7y4r8xLrWStdy0SdgnGqvpaoGBrgxkIA)

I used `this` type in `setAnyMember` to give TS some clues.
I also made illegal state unrepresentable, you can't pass invalid argument to `setAnyMember`

Comment: I like this approach, because it does solve my question, but I dislike it because of casting this. `(this as Record<'sthString' | 'sthBoolean', any> )[field].setValue(val)` is pretty much equivalent to this, and while it works, I hope there is a better solution.

Comment: Sure no problem

Comment: @meougal pls keep in mind that TS does not track mutations. See my article https://catchts.com/mutations